# How to update decision tables automatically?

Tags: business-rules, ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

Is it possible to update registrys of a table decision without manually chagining them? For example if I have a condition column with a date value, I want to delete those lines or transfer them to another table when that date occurs. This in order to keep the amount of rules in a decision table low and make the deployment faster when the business users need to update the table.

If its not possible to change the values in execution mode automatically, perhaps mark such rules as invalid due to the effective date or make them not to be considered when a deployment of the decision table is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Is your main concern execution performance or getting rid of unwanted rules so you don't confuse your business users? If it's performance, I'd advice you to do some performance testing before you spend a lot of time optimizing your rules. ODM/JRules is amazingly efficient, so your otimizations might not be even necessary.

If you want to remove whole rules during deployment, your best chance is the ruleset extractor, which decides which rules to add to a deployment. Take a look here for more information about ruleset extractors: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSQP76_8.7.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.samples/designer_smp_topics/smp_rd_brmrulesetextr_det.html

But in most cases I'd wager, that adding another column with an "effective until" condition column would suffice, since ODM will just ignore these entries without too much of a performance impact.

Comment: Hi sdfx, thanks for the answer. The sample used in the link you provided is using classic rule engine. Im using decision service architecture; 1 mail rule project linked with several rules projects and 1 BOM project. To answer your question, mainly is performance cause I have tables with more than 50000 registrys if I dont move the old ones, but for the user is also easy to see the effective rules left only. Thanks again!